# Cymbidium orchid - black spots on the leaves

Tags: houseplants, diseases, orchids

I bought a cymbidium orchid two days ago. Today I noticed that about 30% of the leaves have black spots on their tips (see the picture). Should I be worried or is it something normal? If it's some kind of disease should I react in any particular way?

Thank you in advance for your help.
[image: Black spots]